# Data structure for concert hall seating plan

Tags: javascript, mongodb, data-structures, database

I am trying to develop a concert seat booking system and I want to draw the seats with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

If the concert hall is just, for instance, 10 rows and 20 seats in each row, I could get the seats with

```
const rows = [
  { name: 'A', seats: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
  { name: 'B', seats: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] },
  { name: 'C', seats: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
  { name: 'D', seats: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
];
```

But what if the concert hall has multiple sections? Would it still just be one object `ConcertHall` with multiple objects `Section`, which each has multiple objects `Row`, which again has multiple seats `Seat`?

So a concert hall looks something like

```
{
  name: "Concert Hall Name",
  sections: [
    {
      name: "Balcon",
      rows: [
        {
          name: "A",
          seats: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want the users to book a ticket for a specific seat, so I guess the seats should be an object on its own. Maybe something like

```
{
  name: "Concert Hall Name",
  sections: [
    {
      name: "Balcon",
      rows: [
        {
          name: "A",
          seats: [
            { id: 'some seat id', name: '1' },
            { id: 'some different seat id', name: '2' },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and then create tickets

```
{
  date: 'some date',
  seatId: 'some seat id'
}
```

Would this work?

Would it be scalable to a concert hall as, for instance, the one at http://www.lcsd.gov.hk/en/hkcc/common/images/facilities/concerthall/concert_hall_seating_plan_s.gif?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
const concertHall = {
    "name": "Example Hall",
    "seats": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "section": "1",
            "row": "A",
            "number": 42
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "section": "VIP Box 1",
            "row": null,
            "number": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "section": "VIP Box 2",
            "row": null,
            "number": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "section": "Wheelchair Box",
            "row": null,
            "number": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Keeps it pretty simple, and every seat has all the info you need.

Then, for a ticket, maybe it will look something like this:

```
{
    "purchased": "2017-03-15T18:30:31.980Z",
    "seatId": 1,
    "holder": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "jdoe@example.com"
    },
    "eventId": 52,
    "price": 102.42,
    "currency": "USD"
}
```

Comment: So you would create all the available tickets, but until someone has bought the ticket, the fields `purchased` and `holder` is null? I think I should maybe have one table for tickets and another table for orders and make the order refer to the ticket when it is bought?

Comment: Hmm sounds like not too bad of an idea. Make all the tickets, so you can keep track of the price. I'd just be sure that if you are going to store orders in a separate table to make sure that there is a unique constraint on `seat, event` so that you don't accidentally sell the seat twice!